# Cannot find module from setup-jest.js

Tags: jest-preset-angular

I have an Angular library that I'm working to update from Angular 11 to 13.  Jest ran fine in 11 and 12, but now I'm having a lot of trouble with v13.  I've followed the [steps outlined here](https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/guides/angular-13+)

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' from 'node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js'

Require stack:
      node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js
      jest.setup.ts

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js:2:24)
```

It seems odd that it's looking for angular core files within the `setup-jest` file.

#### jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json', 'mjs'],
    snapshotSerializers: [
    ],
    roots: ['src'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^lodash-es$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/lodash/index.js'
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.spec.ts'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.mjs?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(jest-test))', 'node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)', 'node_modules/(?!\\@angular)'],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
    coverageReporters: ['json', 'text', 'html', 'cobertura'],
    reporters: ['default', ['jest-junit', { outputDirectory: 'TestResults', outputName: 'jest-junit.xml' }]],
};
```

#### jest.setup.ts

```js
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/testing';
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-lib-name",
  "version": "12.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:types && npm run build:umd && npm run build:esm2015 && npm run build:app",
    "build:app": "tsc --project tsconfig.app.json",
    "build:types": "tsc --project tsconfig.app.json --emitDeclarationOnly",
    "build:umd": "tsc --project tsconfig.umd.json",
    "build:esm2015": "tsc --project tsconfig.esm2015.json",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "test": "jest --watch-all --detect-open-handles --reporters=default",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --ext .ts ./src",
    "ci:test": "jest --ci --no-cache --maxWorkers=4 --detect-open-handles --coverage",
    "postbuild": "node scripts/postbuild.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.13.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.11",
    "@types/chance": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/estree": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.2",
    "chance": "^1.1.8",
    "date-fns": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^31.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "jest-marbles": "^2.5.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^12.2.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ng-packagr": "^12.2.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which builder are you using for the test architect target in angular.json?

Comment: What's are the file contents of `tsconfig.spec.json`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are on an old version of Jest (version 26). Jest Preset Angular version 12 [requires Jest version 28](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jest-preset-angular@12.2.0/package.json).

[According to Jest Preset Angular's documentation](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular#configuration), you are missing this setting in `jest.config.js`:

```json
module.exports = {
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
}
```

Make sure to review [Jest Preset Angular's migration guide for Angular 13](https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/guides/angular-13+/).

Comment: Thank you so much!  Updating the Jest version and adding the globalSetup got things working again!  I definitely didn't realize Jest was out of date (I don't recall getting any warnings when I installed jest-preset-angular).

Comment: I inspected the `peerDependencies` of `jest-preset-angular`: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jest-preset-angular@12.2.0/package.json (now added to the answer).